# Castor Lists Polymorphism

Tags: java, xml, marshalling, castor

I have a quick Castor question. I would like to use Castor mapping to marshal a list of objects. These objects are of two different types, both extending the same abstract base class. I would like them to have different tags in the xml, but both be added to the same list. They also have slightly different fields. Is this possible? If so, how?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible to marshal to XML. Use

```
<bind-xml auto-naming="deriveByClass" .../>
```

in the declaration of your list field, and define separate mappings for the two classes that are members of your list. It'll then use the `map-to`  to output different XML node names, and each `class` mapping to determine different content. You can also use the `extends` attribute on the base class so you only need to map the members of the base class once, too.